# Limit access to firestore based on query conditions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have some firestore data as follows:

```
/team/[id]

{
  teamName: "My team"
  members: []
  inviteCode: "jfds621jd"
}
```

I'd like to write a security rule so that any user can read any team, but only if they query based on the invite code. Otherwise, I only want them to be able to read a team if their auth.uid is in the members array.

In other words, this query should succeed for any user:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('teams').where('inviteCode', '==', 'jfds621jd');
```

But something like this (not querying based on inviteCode) should fail, unless the current UID is in the members array.

```
firebase.firestore().collection('teams').get()
```

Having some trouble figuring this out. There doesn't appear to be a way to access the query "where" conditions in the security rules.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with security rules, because it's not really secure at all.

If you want to make a simple plaintext password system, you will have to create a backend that checks a parameter that you pass to it.  It can perform the query, check the value of the document field for equality with the password, and then choose to send the document contents (or not).

Security rules can validate and reject the data going into a document for write operations, but it can't validate the query filters and reject based on what it sees in each document.

In short, if you want to allow public query access (`list` permission) on a collection, the entire world can effectively see the entire collection, and filter it (or not filter it) as they want.  The only things about the query you may use in security rules are what's documented for [request.query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#query).

Perhaps you want to instead invite specific user account using the UID or some other data provided by Firebase Auth, as identified in `request.auth`.